# AngularJs show products in multiple pages

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a webApp in `AngularJs` where I have some products. These products are shown in different pages with different states (favorite/ not favorite), for example:

- Home page - All products;
- Category page - Products in this specific category;
- Company page - Products from this specific company;
- User page - If user is logged;

It also has an option of 'favorite product', which is enabled only if the user is logged.

#### My doubt is, how can I:

- Load the list of proucts only once?
- Apply a `favorite=true` only when user is logged?
- Filter the product list based on category or company?
- Have a function to toggle the favorite?

The problem I'm facing right now is because in the category page, I need to filter the list. Reading some articles, they recomend to not use `filter | {condition}` inside `ng-repeat`, instead, use `$filter` inside controller. Since this app deal with a lot of products I'm trying to stick with it (also, already did some basic tests and had improvement).

---

#### What I have:

Currently, since I'm using `ui-router`, I'm loading the data on the `resolve` of the state and then I'll pass it to my `mainController`.

```
.state('app', { //Main State
    resolve: {
        mainProduct: function (factMain) {
            var func = 'get_product';
            return factMain.methodGet(func);
        }
    }
})
```

Ok, now I have the list and can use it. In the `mainController` I check if the user is logged in each `stateChangeStart`, if he's logged, I'll load the list of favorites he has and update the products with an `angular.forEach`. All of this inside the `mainController`.

After that I need to show these products based on the page the user is, for example, if he's in the homepage, there is no problem, everything is done, I just need to show the products.

But if he's in the category 'shoes', I need to filter this list to show only 'shoes' and also, check for the favorites products.

I'm getting the list inside the `categoryController` with a reference from the main state resolve, like this:

```
.state('category/:idCategory', { //Main State
    resolve: {
        categoryProduct: function (mainProduct) {
            return mainProduct;
        }
    }
})
```

But then I'll have to re-do everything again... Check if user is logged, apply favorites, filter the list, send to the `HTML`.

I'd like to optimize this process. I tried to use a `factory` to set this products list, but since it has some $http waiting for a promise, if I first enter the 'Category Page' before the home page, the products aren't set yet.

Inside the `factory` I tried to use these functions: `setProduct`, `getProduct`, `clearProduct` (to clear the favorites states when user log out).

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: In the ng-repeat that shows all these products, have it point to some list of products, call it `shownProducts`. Then have another list of all the products, called something like `allProducts`. Then, using the JavaScript function .filter(), have `shownProducts = allProducts.filter( [logic] )`, but change the filter based on what you want.

Comment: The logic of .filter can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: The problem isn't that much with the filter itself, but with the view and the list I have to apply to that view. The homepage list will have all the products (let's say 1.500 un), while the category list 'shoes' will contain only 80un. The problem is to make this list avaliable in all the controllers without the need to reload them over and over again and also apply the favorites to the main list, not only to the view list. If you can understand what I mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you last comment first, you could store the results of a request and then retrieve and re-use them when you need.
First of all, I would place all requests in a service or factory.

```
app.factory('DataService', function($http) {
  var categories;
  var requestCategories = function() {
    $http.get("/api/getCategories").then(
        function(results){
            categories = results;
        });
  };
  var getCategories = function() {
    return categories;
  };
  return {
    requestCategories : requestCategories, // this will make a http request and store the result
    getCategories : getCategories // this will call the stored result (without making a http request)
  }
});
```

Now you have two functions, `requestCategories` and `getCategories`.

`requestCategories` will make the http request when called and store the return values in a variable
`getCategories` will get the values from the variable, without making a request

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, DataService) {
  var init = function (){
    DataService.requestCategories(); // this will make the http request and store the result
    $scope.categories = DataService.getCategories(); // this will get the result
  };

  var justGetValues = function(){
    $scope.categories= DataService.getCategories(); // this will get the result (without making a http request)
  };
});
```

Now that you have all the categories stored you can now [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to filter and toggle what to display on

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:{ type: by_type }"> // by property
```

or

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories | filter: by_favorites"> // by custom filter
```

and code for your custom filter:

```
app.filter('by_favorites', function () {
  return function (items) {
    var filtered = [];
    // do logic here
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Comment: It's kind of solving my problem, but I understood the logic. I was trying to send the data from the resolve state to a factory, instead of request inside it, like you did. Now is just a question of migrate the functions inside the factory like you said. About the filter, i read it's not a good practice to have filter with ng-repeat in huge datas, so i'll do it inside each controller when necessary. But thanks, you guided me throught it.